# Help prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n/2} (\frac{ne}{k})^k(1-1.8\frac{\ln(n)}{n})^{k(n-k)} = 0$

Tags: limits

I am trying to prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^{n/2} (\frac{ne}{k})^k(1-1.8\frac{\ln(n)}{n})^{k(n-k)} = 0,$$
but did not manage to get far. I tried using the same techniques as proposed in
[How to evaluate $ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sum \limits_ {k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164074/how-to-evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-k-1n-fracknn) and [$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\ln k}{n} ( 1-\{\frac{n}{k} \} ) ( (1-\frac{k}{n} \{\frac{n}{k}\} )-\frac{1}{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221269/lim-n-to-infty-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-ln-kn-1-fracnk), but did not see how these could be expanded to work in my case. Any hints in how to solve the limit are very welcome. I am especially struggling with the fact that the summation only goes to $n/2$, not to $n$.

Comment: It is an odd looking expression. How did you end up with this problem?

Comment: It appears in Lemma 3 of this paper https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204_2018/Lee_Bernick_paper.pdf, for proving the connectivity of ER-graphs.

Comment: The lemma is given with $\lambda>1$, whereas it is $\lambda=0.8$ in your case. I plot your expression as a function of $n$ and it seems to tend to infinity and not $0$. I tried it with $1.1$ and it indeed tends to $0$ as given by the lemma.

Comment: @Gary, that should indeed have been $\lambda = 1.8$, thank you! I edited it now..

Answer (score 1):

The summands can be bounded as follows
\begin{align*}
& \le \left( {\frac{{ne}}{k}} \right)^k \exp \left( { - 1.8\frac{{\log n}}{n}k(n - k)} \right) = \left( {\frac{e}{k}} \right)^k \exp \left( {k\left( {1 - 1.8\frac{{n - k}}{n}} \right)\log n} \right).
\end{align*}
For $1 \le k \le \left[ {0.4n} \right]$ the right-hand side is at most
$$
\left( {\frac{e}{k}} \right)^k \exp \left( { - \frac{1}{2}\log n} \right) = \left( {\frac{e}{k}} \right)^k \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }},
$$
whereas for $\left[ {0.4n} \right] < k \le \left[ {0.5n} \right]$, it is at most
$$
\left( {\frac{e}{k}} \right)^k \exp \left( {\frac{n}{{20}}\log n} \right) \le \left( {\frac{e}{{0.4n}}} \right)^{0.4n} \exp \left( {\frac{n}{{20}}\log n} \right) = n^{ - 7n/20} \left( {\frac{e}{{0.4}}} \right)^{0.4n}  < n^{ - 7n/20} 3^n .
$$So your sum (which is positive) can be bounded from above by
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\left[ {0.4n} \right]} {\left( {\frac{e}{k}} \right)^k \frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}}  + \sum\limits_{k = \left[ {0.4n} \right] + 1}^{\left[ {0.5n} \right]} {n^{ - 7n/20} 3^n }  = \mathcal{O}(1)\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }} + \mathcal{O}(1)n^{1 - 7n/20} 3^n  = \mathcal{O}(1)\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}.
$$